# what would be most efficient, complex join/from or inline select?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

if you look at these 2 examples, which one would be "proper"? assuming both are working and both are returning the same result

is there a 3rd way?

if the second one is the best way, is it possible to include the 3 inline select into the join/from?

```
var test1 = (from m in MasterList
            join m1 in Master1 on m.id equals m1.id
            select new 
            {
                Prop1 = m1,
                Prop2 = Master2.Where(x => x.id2 == m1.id2).SingleOrDefault(),
                Prop3 = Master3.Where(x => x.id2 == m1.id2).SingleOrDefault(),
                Prop4 = Master4.Where(x => x.id2 == m1.id2).ToList(),
                Prop5 = Master5.Where(x => x.id2 == m1.id2).ToList(),
                Prop6 = Master6.Where(x => x.id == m.id).Select(x => x.id2).SingleOrDefault(),
                Prop7 = m.id3,
                Prop8 = m.id4,
                Prop9 = m.id5,

            }).ToList();

var test2 = (from m in MasterList
            join m1 in Master1 on m.id equals m1.id
            join m2 in Master2 on m1.id2 equals m2.id2 into m2left
            from m2l in m2left.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join m3 in Master3 on m1.id2 equals m3.id2 into m3left
            from m3l in m3left.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                Prop1 = m1,
                Prop2 = m2l,
                Prop3 = m3l,
                Prop4 = Master4.Where(x => x.id2 == m1.id2).ToList(),
                Prop5 = Master5.Where(x => x.id2 == m1.id2).ToList(),
                Prop6 = Master6.Where(x => x.id == m.id).Select(x => x.id2).SingleOrDefault(),
                Prop7 = m.id3,
                Prop8 = m.id4,
                Prop9 = m.id5,

            }).ToList();
```

Comment: I'd go with the first if it works until it's really too slow. It's more reeadable and maintainable. Have you noticed a difference at all? [If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I'm going to do some benchmark later today with both or tomorrow morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is generally faster and *vastly* more scalable IF you inner lists are likely to be of any size.  The performance of sub-selects vs joins is well discussed in the sql world.

basically, at least for linq to objects, there is nothing that is going to optimize away your subselects, and thus you WILL enumerate the inner sets over and over again.  If they are of any size this is potentially very expensive.

Look at the benchmarks of this simplified example, the code is below (these in 32 bit and release mode).

```
Test for SUBSELECT master=100000;a=10000;b=10 took 12ms and returned 10000
Test for SUBSELECT master=100000;a=10000;b=100 took 7ms and returned 10000
Test for SUBSELECT master=100000;a=10000;b=1000 took 41ms and returned 10000
Test for SUBSELECT master=100000;a=10000;b=10000 took 387ms and returned 10000
Test for SUBSELECT master=100000;a=10000;b=100000 took 3803ms and returned 10000
Test for SUBSELECT master=100000;a=10000;b=1000000 took 38172ms and returned 10000

Test for JOIN master=100000;a=10000;b=10 took 14ms and returned 10000
Test for JOIN master=100000;a=10000;b=100 took 4ms and returned 10000
Test for JOIN master=100000;a=10000;b=1000 took 4ms and returned 10000
Test for JOIN master=100000;a=10000;b=10000 took 7ms and returned 10000
Test for JOIN master=100000;a=10000;b=100000 took 13ms and returned 10000
Test for JOIN master=100000;a=10000;b=1000000 took 297ms and returned 10000
```

You can see that for the subselect, with everything else fixed the timings scale up linearly with the size of the inner set. The join version if fairly flat, until b > master and a, whence it drives up the query time.

This is because, basically, the join keyword can kick of a hash join and enumerate each side only once (memory allowing) and thus basically just scale with the largest set size, again there are many discussions of this is a DB context out on the net.

I will answer your list question shortly.

Example Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Just looking at how the size of the INNER set affects time
        TimedTest(100000, 10000, 10);
        TimedTest(100000, 10000, 100);
        TimedTest(100000, 10000, 1000);
        TimedTest(100000, 10000, 10000);
        TimedTest(100000, 10000, 100000);
        TimedTest(100000, 10000, 1000000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void TimedTest(int masterSize, int aSize, int bSize)
    {
        var masterList = Enumerable.Range(1, masterSize).ToArray();
        var aList = Enumerable.Range(1, aSize).ToArray();
        var bList = Enumerable.Range(1, bSize).ToArray();
        var w = new Stopwatch();
        //Subselect
        w.Restart();
        var x = (from m in masterList
                 join a in aList on m equals a
                 select new { B = bList.Where(b => b == m).SingleOrDefault() }).ToList();
        w.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Test for SUBSELECT master={0};a={1};b={2} took {3}ms and returned {4}", masterSize, aSize, bSize, w.ElapsedMilliseconds, x.Count);
        w.Restart();
        var y = (from m in masterList
                 join a in aList on m equals a
                 join b in bList on a equals b into bLeft
                 from bl in bLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new { B = bl }).ToList();
        w.Stop();
        Debug.Assert(x.SequenceEqual(y));
        Console.WriteLine("Test for JOIN master={0};a={1};b={2} took {3}ms and returned {4}", masterSize, aSize, bSize, w.ElapsedMilliseconds, y.Count);

        //Join

    }
```

For the 'list' items.  You can pre-group them BEFORE the join and thus you have:

```
static void Example()
{
    var masterSize = 10000;
    var aSize = 1000;
    var bSize = 100000;
    var masterList = Enumerable.Range(1, masterSize).ToArray();
    var aList = Enumerable.Range(1, aSize).ToArray();
    var bList = Enumerable.Range(1, bSize).Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, bSize)).ToArray();
    var w = new Stopwatch();
    //Subselect
    w.Restart();
    var x = (from m in masterList
             join a in aList on m equals a
             select new { A=a, M=m, B = bList.Where(b => b == m).ToList() }).ToList();
    w.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Test for SUBSELECT master={0};a={1};b={2} took {3}ms and returned {4}", masterSize, aSize, bSize, w.ElapsedMilliseconds, x.Count);
    //Join
    w.Restart();
    var y = (from m in masterList
             join a in aList on m equals a
             join b in (from b in bList group b by b) on m equals b.Key into bLeft
             from bl in bLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { A = a, M = m, B = bl.ToList() }).ToList();
    w.Stop();
    Debug.Assert(x.Select(i => new { A = i.A, BC = i.B.Sum() }).SequenceEqual(y.Select(i => new { A = i.A, BC = i.B.Sum() })));
    Console.WriteLine("Test for JOIN master={0};a={1};b={2} took {3}ms and returned {4}", masterSize, aSize, bSize, w.ElapsedMilliseconds, y.Count);      

}
```

ie in the terms of you question:

```
....
            join m4 in (from m4 in Master4 group m4 by m4.id) on m1.id2 equals m4.Key into m4left
            from m4l in m4left.DefaultIfEmpty()
....
            Prop4 = m4l.ToList()
```

Comment: just to make sure, is this apply to **linq to object**? because my question is not about sql.

Comment: Yes its about linq to object, the example is a linq to object example, I am just refering to DB docs because that is where most of the literature about different styles of joining / filtering large lists has been centred in recent history.  In fact a DB engine behind a linq to entities MAY decide to implement the subselect AS a  join, ie because linq to entities MIGHT optimise you might NOT see this kid of performance profile there